# how to decode string like this c'ÃƒÂƒÃ‚Â¨

Tags: php

I want to decode a string like c'ÃƒÂƒÃ‚Â¨ in utf8.
When encoding or / and decoding from one to another character-set is made, typical strings appear that show that something went wrong.
Is it possible for the posted string to reconstruct the origin utf-8 string?

Comment: Where did you get such string in the first place?

Comment: Decode into what? Don't you just want to pass it out still as UTF-8 for display?

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: I did some decoding of this kind of text to translate it into html friendly text (you know, starts with &#xx). https://github.com/hellonearthis/ascii2web

Comment: Those strings are common for some wrong conversions between character sets and it can be tried to find the solution by verifying the single characters - an UTF-8 character consist of several characters in ANSII where they never have any meaning.
A debugging table can be found here: https://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html

Comment: Possible "Double Mis-Conversion" can happen too as described here: https://www.i18nqa.com/debug/bug-double-conversion.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to change 'strange' characters like ä Ü into their equivalents a U, then this might help:

[**PHP Normalizer class**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php)

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'Normalizer' not found

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say what you mean with “decoding” the string. A string in UTF-8 is just a valid string as it stands. You can *convert* it to another encoding, but you do not state which one you want to use. So, to *convert* a string from one encoding (e.g. UTF-8) to another (e.g. iso-8859-2), you can use e.g. the [`iconv()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) function, e.g.:

```
iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-2", $text)
```

But be aware that there are many characters in Unicode (and UTF-8) which cannot be represented in a particular single-byte character set; check the PHP documentation for your options in such cases. (You might be able to just use the string in UTF-8, which is probably the best encoding available, anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

If I do:

```
$string="c'ÃƒÂƒÃ‚Â¨";
echo mb_detect_encoding($string);
```

I'd get:

```
UTF-8
```

Comment: Well, how is your PHP file encoded?